# C++ polymorphism, virtual functions error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I got the problem with virtual methods of my C++ projects.

First of all i got the class graphics which presents:

```
#pragma once
class gameGraphics
{
public:
    gameGraphics();
    ~gameGraphics();
    virtual void paint();
};
```

and i got two classes, first one :

```
class brick 
    : public gameGraphics
{
protected:
    int R, G, B;
    bool ifDelete;
public:
    brick();
    ~brick();
    virtual void paint(int x, int y);
};
```

And the second one:

```
class superBrick :
    public brick, public gameGraphics
{
private:
    int bonusType;
public:
    superBrick();
    ~superBrick();
    void paint(int x, int y);
};
```

Then im trying to paint objects of this two classes, when my projects runs it shows error: "Unhandled exception at 0x74D3CB49 in project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.", while trying paint function for superBrick object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < LENGTH; k++)
    {
        temp = &table[k][i];
        temp->paint(k, i);
    }
}
```

I dont know what is the reason of this error, i think i did the Polymorphism good.

Sorry for my english, thanks for reading and help!

Have a good night!

EDIT:

class of table here:

```
class gameTable : public gameGraphics
{
private:
    brick** table;
public:
    gameTable();
    ~gameTable();
    void paint(int CordX, int cordY);   
};
```

Comment: Your destructors need to be `virtual`.

Comment: I doubt the polymorphism would be the cause of your access violation, and you are not showing much code. You might want to virtualize the inheritance to gameGraphics from brick and superBrick, though. Read about the diamond problem.

Comment: I suspect that you have gone outside the bounds of `table`. Can you create this error with a single `superBrick` object?

Comment: You should use a debugger to see what line causes the access violation. Also note superBrick inherits from gameGraphics twice. I'm guessing this is not what you wanted.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help, particularly the declaration of `table`.
I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: I'm not leaving my table that's sure. Using the virtual destructors in every class, didnt help me also. What mind be imporatant, i tried it before to not use virtual paint in brick and superBrick classes. When i did that, my project was using only brick class paint method even for superBrick object.

Comment: lass gameTable : public gameGraphics
{
private:
 brick** table;
public:
 gameTable();
 ~gameTable();
 void paint(int CordX, int cordY); 
};

Comment: (1) not virtual destructor, (2) multiple inheritance, (3) various signatures for virtual function, (4) `ifDelete` flag, (5) no use of `const`, (6) apparently using macros for constants, like `WIDTH`, (7) needless use of pointers (like `temp`), (8) use of raw arrays instead of e.g. `std::vector`, (9) double-star

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the source of your problem

```
    temp = &table[k][i];
```

You can't have polymorphism with an array of objects because they would all be of the same class.

You've omitted the definition of table but it probably should be an array of pointer that can reference different classes with the same parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Access violation executing location 0x00000000 . This means you are dereferencing a null ptr ( a pointer of address 0. So the access violation is that you can't reference memory at location 0. Either table is null or table[k] is null. Make sure table is initialized with brick ptrs.

Also check "Cheers and hth" comments for good coding suggestions.